# how can I detect whether the http and https service is ok in python?

Tags: python, http, https

I want to detect wheter the `http` or `https` service is ok, in `python`.

Now I have known is to use `httplib` module.

Use the  `httplib.HTTPConnection` to get the status, and check whether it is 'OK'(code is 200), and the same to https by using `HTTPSConnection`

but I don't know whether this way is right?or there is another more good way?

Comment: @freakish but there is a question, treat different url path in one host, thre getresponse().status is different, i test my vps, the ip is 403, but the domain in it it 200（ok），does the http service relate to the url path?

Comment: @Maulwurfn I test different url path in one host, and the status returned is different , why?

Comment: @TankyWoo I'm not sure I understand. You are trying different URLs and you get different responses? That depends on the server you are trying to connect to. It may (and it mostly will) treat different URLs differently. For example if it is a static files server, then it will respond with 404 if the file does not exists ( base on the URL ). 403 means that you do not have access to the service ( authentication required ).

Comment: @freakish yes, that is the question. But what I do is only want to detect whether the host's http service is ok. no matter what the url path is in the host. So how could I do?

Comment: @TankyWoo What do you mean by "ok"? As long as you have a response code (whatever it is) it means that the server responded with something.

Comment: @freakish 'ok' means this service is 'running'. use that way, get the status code relate to the url path, but I want to know the http service is ok or wrong only by the host itself.

Comment: @TankyWoo What do you mean by "running"? :) Tanky, whatever the server responds with ( whatever the code is ) it means that it is running. Response code 403 or 500 or whatever means that the service is running but you tried to do something that the server cannot process. But the service **is** running. The only possibility is that there is no host at all. In this case you need to use timeouts, like Emmanuel suggested.

Comment: @freakish ok,thank you. I know. ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a script that does this kind of check, I use `urllib2` for that, whatever the protocol (http or https):

```
result = False
error = None
try:
    # Open URL
    urllib2.urlopen(url, timeout=TIMEOUT)
    result = True
except urllib2.URLError as exc:
    error = 'URL Error: {0}'.format(str(exc))
except urllib2.HTTPError as exc:
    error = 'HTTP Error: {0}'.format(str(exc))
except Exception as exc:
    error = 'Unknow error: {0}'.format(str(exc))
```